# how to create new line after inline <ul> elements

Tags: html, css

I have inline ul li elements. After ul I am displaying div, but div elements are not coming in new line.
How to display div after ul elements not parellely ul elements.

Below is my code.

```css
.nav {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">My Cart</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
  <h1> Sample Text</h1>
  <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `clear: both;` into your `div` element next to `ul` would do the job. Obviously there are better solution for this now. You can explore and read about `flex` and `grid` if you want.

```css
.nav {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.nav+div {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">My Cart</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
  <h1> Sample Text</h1>
  <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the most simple and straightfoward answer, +1. `clear` is exactly there for tis exact thing: clearing floats. I do not see any reason why it would be inferiour to flexboxes or other more modern approaches.

Comment: The reason is that `float` was never meant to be used for layouting purposes, like the one you require. People have been using it only due to a lack of better alternatives, which now exist **and should be preferred**.

Comment: @connexo Fair, and I agree with the semantics. But as it is not causing any problems to use it for this (though technically "off-label") usecase, I feel like just clearing the float to fix the issue is the most simple approach to solve the issue.

Comment: So you consider **applying a fix to a solution that is actually causing the problem** in the first place *the most simple approach*? I strongly disagree.

Answer (score 2):

> The float property is used for positioning and formatting content e.g. let an image float left to the text in a container. ~W3Schools

Your `float:left` doing that, just remove it from `.nav`.

```css
.nav {
  list-style: none;     
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  display:inline;
}

/* I think this is what you trying to achive, right? */
.nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="active" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Cart</a></li>
    </ul>
    
<div>
    <h1> Sample Text</h1>
    <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ulou-How to display UL li elements at right side without using float?

Comment: You mean one to each other in one line?

Comment: Yes, how to display li elements inline at right side without using float:right

Comment: You just put `float` for wrong element. It should be for `.nav li` not for `.nav`. I've updated snippet.

Comment: @ulou adding the float to the  li would not change the issue. This simply is what `clear` is for, and it is necessary.

Comment: @JohannesH. Did you run the snippet? `clear` is used, when you want to prevent floating of siblings elements. You do not need to clear here, cause every element inside `ul` needs float.

Answer (score 1):

You made your whole `ul.nav` element `float: left;`.

<del>What you probably really want instead is your `list-items` to have `display: inline-block;`.</del>

Edit: As per your new requirement, I've used CSS grid to put your links on one line and align them to the right side of the page.

```css
.nav {
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: end;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

.nav li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">My Cart</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
  <h1> Sample Text</h1>
  <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if I want to display li elements at right side of page , how to achieve that without using float:right?

Comment: Check the edit. If you want the same code to align them to the left, just remove the `justify-content: end;` part.

Answer (score 0):

try to make the parent flexible and control the chillds i just gave you the general idea

```
.nav, li {
  list-style: none;     
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  display:flex;
}

/*here we gonna controle the cillds */
.nav li a {
   flex-direction:row;
   justify-content:space-around;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="active" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Cart</a></li>
    </ul>
    
<div>
    <h1> Sample Text</h1>
    <p>Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```